# Default parameters not working as expected

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, dataset, default

I have a report shown below using 3 parameters. I would want to see values automatically populated when I open up the report.

But it shows as below:

[image: Parameter not showing default values]

[image: AvailableValues]

[image: DefaultValues]

```
Dataset1:

SELECT DISTINCT 
LectCode, LectName, AgeBand, RegYear, PRPH_ML1, 
[Curriculum Area], PRPH_Title, Section, Section_Name, 
Class_Register COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + Register_Title 
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + Register_Day 
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + '  ' + CONVERT(char(5),
StartTime, 108) + ' - ' + CONVERT(char(5), EndTime, 108) AS Register, 
CourseType, Mins_Poss, Mins_Att, Mins_Late, TermTimeWeekNo, 
WeekStart, Class_Register, 
Register_Title, Register_Day, StartTime, EndTime, 
PrimaryProgramme, LectSection, LectDepartment
FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
WHERE        (RegYear = @Year) AND (CourseType IN (@CourseType)) 
AND (LectName IN (@Lecturer))
GROUP BY LectCode, LectName, AgeBand, RegYear, PRPH_ML1, 
[Curriculum Area], PRPH_Title, Section, Section_Name, 
CourseType, Mins_Poss, Mins_Att, Mins_Late, 
TermTimeWeekNo, WeekStart, Class_Register, Register_Title,
 Register_Day, StartTime, EndTime, 
 PrimaryProgramme, LectSection, LectDepartment
ORDER BY LectName, CourseType

Dataset2:
SELECT DISTINCT CourseType
FROM CurrentAttendance_New


Dataset3:

SELECT DISTINCT LectName
FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
WHERE        (CourseType IN (@CourseType))
```

I made sure I am using values from above datasets and setting default values as well.

Let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: It looks as if the defaults for Lecturer are not set, or are set incorrectly.  Can you provide more information about how you are setting this default value?

Comment: Pictures of the Parameter Dialogue box would also help.

Answer (score 1):

In your `WHERE` clause, do you have all of the parameter set?

`WHERE @PLUMBING_VACANCY_3= "YES"`, etc.

Also, if these values should be selected at load, they should be changed in the Default Values under the Parameter Properties and set your Parameters = to your value(s).